# Hibernate is not responding while querying

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, querydsl

How to handle if Hibernate queries take too long to return the result. I have already configured a query time out but on debugging it shows that the DB is responding by returning data, but hibernate fails to map the given data.

I do not want this scenario to happen in production, because my query might fail since the hibernate is not responding back.

I need a solution to come out from this scenario.

```
setProperty("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 180000);

JPAQuery query = queryFactory.select(....)
do{
   List<Tuple> data = query.fetch().limit(5000);
   //--------
} while(flag)
```

The above code works fine with data which are less in size, but for some data sets/ conditions the data is huge and eventually hibernate is not responding.

Comment: we need more information, like some of your code , how you build the query, how the pojo is, how you are wrapping the result of the query into your class, etc etc

Comment: Query is out of plain querydsl, and queried through hibernate DAO repository. There are 130 columns in the DB with 2 columns contains huge data. Which we are exporting to a csv file.

Comment: Basically i want hibernate to auto terminate request if it is taking too long

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow these steps, if

- Use Lazy Fetching instead of Eager Fetching like `@ManyToMany(mappedBy="authors", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`
- Or May be check if any of these [Mistakes](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/common-hibernate-mistakes-cripple-performance/)
- You are using `HibernateDaoSupport.getSession()`, without ever returning them using releaseSession() (as described in the javadocs).

a) use `HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()` to cleanly create/destroy sessions 
b) use `getSession()/releaseSession()` in a finally block
c) forget about `HibernateDaoSupport`, define transactions and use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`

- use, `session.refresh(entity) or entityManager.refresh(entity)` (if you use JPA) will give you fresh data from DB.

Answer (score 1):

```
1) For setting the timeout in Hibernate query you can set hint "javax.persistence.query.timeout"


Code snippet ::

List<Test> test= em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM Test t")
    .setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 1)
    .getResultList();

2) In case 2 columns are containing large data ,you can use CLOB and BLOB types for huge dataset.
```

Comment: javax.persistence.query.timeout already taken care, but the time is taking on the mapping part since the data fetch size i guess was more.

Comment: I could only reduce fetch size dynamically only if the given fetch size is not responding

Comment: What is the datatype of those 2 columns?

Comment: Text in postgres

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, you are looking for a way to manage a timeout for certains queries.

You can achieve this while creating your `org.hibernate.Query` with Hibernate:

```
Query queryObject = //initialize your query as you need;
queryObject.setTimeout(10); //that int represents the seconds of timeouts.
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have set the same on my hibernate configuration and it doesn't seems to be working since query returns the result but hibernate not.

Comment: set time out - i couldn't find that implementation straight on JPAQuery though i have set that in the hibernate level

Comment: that's why I've asked more details in my first comment: if you don't add some code in your question we can just assume what you are doing :)

Comment: I have added a very basic piece of code on what i am dealing with

Answer (score 0):

Finally i couldn't find any direct way to get control over a hibernate query call.
The time out was not working for me since the Postgres already returned the result set but hibernate was taking time in mapping (correct me if i am wrong) due to data size.

Following piece of code saved me.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
List<Future<List<Tuple>>> futureData = executor.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(new QueryService(params...)), 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
executor.shutdown();
for (Future future : futureData) {
    try {
         data = (List<Tuple>) future.get();
         } catch (CancellationException e) {
                 if (EXPORT_LIMIT > 1000) {
                            EXPORT_LIMIT = 1000;
                        } else if (EXPORT_LIMIT > 500) {
                            EXPORT_LIMIT = 500;
                        } else if (EXPORT_LIMIT > 100) {
                            EXPORT_LIMIT = 100;
                        } else {
                            throw e;
                        }
                        isValid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

So basically my default fetch limit of 5000 if not working, then i keep trying till 100.
If fetch size of 100 is also failing an exception will be thrown.

Thank you.